# filter string "<div>" and </div> for input textfield <div contenteditable..., jquery, js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot get `filter string` `"<div>"` for `input textfield` `<div contenteditble.`

i have in admin side `<div contenteditable.....` and any times it happen that users insert string `<div>` in input text when we copy - paste text data from other text editors.

when `<div>` is saved, the page does not load properly.

i have tried

```
var axtbody = axtbody.replace("<div>",'');
```

or

```
var axtbody = axtbody.replace(/<div>/,'');
```

but it is not working.

I want to obtain filter for input text when `"<div>"` string is disallowed for input in textfield and for example 
 is allowed or any other char or accents is allowed.

Comment: `var axtbody = axtbody.replace("<div>",'');`

Is very strange. You're declaring `axtbody` but you're also assuming it already has a value.

Can you show a bit more code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex below:

```
"Hello, <div>how are</div> you.".replace(/<\/?div>/g, '');
```

The result will be:

```
"Hello, how are you."
```

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense, you are declaring a variable and then trying to access it's contents before it has any:

```
var axtbody = axtbody.replace("<div>",'');
```

I think you want something like this:

```
var axtbody = "abcd <div> 1234";

axtbody = axtbody.replace("<div>",'');

alert(axtbody);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ueRn/

Answer (score 0):

The basic process is to get the value from the text field, remove the text you don't want, and then set the value on the text field again.

```
var input = document.getElementById(...);

input.value = input.value.replace(/<\/?div.*?>/gi, "");
```